# How to make a display mode of the current user on the home page?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a site built with Drupal 8 and the Twig Tweak module. I want to make the current user's `frontpage_tasks` display mode on my home page. How to do this ?

I can make a user's `frontpage_tasks` display mode by manually entering their ID :

page--front.html.twig :

```
{{ drupal_entity('user', 51, 'frontpage_tasks') }}
{{ drupal_entity('commerce_store', ???, 'frontpage_tasks') }}
{{ drupal_entity('group', ???, 'frontpage_tasks') }}
```

For stores, I want to display all stores that the current user owns.

For groups, I want to display all groups whose current user is the creator.

What I want to do is render the current user account, stores and groups with `frontpage_tasks` view mode.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113740/discussion-on-question-by-mathieu-how-to-make-a-display-mode-of-the-current-user).

Comment: The problem is that a page normally shouldn't  have a cache dependency for the current user. If you placed this as a block via the block layout this dependency would be resolved automatically. This block could be built by a custom block plugin or Views.

Comment: @4k4 I don't want to save my view, I want to delete it. I'm trying to put a simple TWIG code. I don't have a cache problem. No problem making the display mode current user. I still have to do the stores and groups of the current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Twig template you can get the current user id with `user.id`.

With the help of Twig Tweak you can use it to render the user entity:

```
{{ drupal_entity('user', user.id, 'full') }}
```

As discussed in the comments this only works if your template has already a cache context for the current user.

Comment: I already have the answer from Sssweat and it works. My problem is with stores and groups. See chat

Comment: I took a different approach in answering the original question with the main focus on caching. For other topics like stores or groups please ask separate questions providing more details.